# CakePHP submit button Image

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, form-submit

I am trying to use image for a submit button

```
<?php echo $this->Form->submit('/img/prelaunch/btn_signup.gif'); ?>
```

thats the code i am using. but the image is not able to load The image is present in the following directory

> Webroot/img/prelaunch/

**Updated**

HTML Generated

```
<div class="submit">
<input type="image" src="/ginger/img/prelaunch/btn_signup.gif">
</div>
```

**Webiste Base URL** http://bakasura.in/ginger/

**URL** http://bakasura.in/ginger/users/signup

**Image URL** http://bakasura.in/ginger/img/prelaunch/btn_signup.jpg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The image is a jpg, you have put a gif in the submit button source code. Simple mistake :D

Comment: i tried that and its not working i have added the Link plz have a look

Comment: @Harsha M V Edited answer to answer question now we have more info

Comment: Holy COW :( Thanks dude. Damn. copy pasting code.. gets u into serious trouble. Thanks buddy

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is:

```
<?php echo $form->submit('Sign up', array('type'=>'image','src' => '/img/prelaunch/btn_signup.gif'));  ?>
```

from: http://php-freelancer.in/2010/04/28/cakephp-how-to-make-image-submit-button/

Answer (score 1):

Just create a class name in css and add the image

Form->submit('submit',array('class'=>'show-image')); ?>

### CSS

.show-image{
background-image:url(../img/prelaunch/btn_signup.gif); background-repeat:no-repeat; display:block; width:30px; height:30pxtext-transform:capitalize;
}

Answer (score 0):

I created a custom button using an image in my under app/webroot/img that uses inline style for specifying size and changing the position to center

```
$options=array('type'=>'Make secure payment', 'type'=>'image', 'style'=>'width:200px; height:80px; display:block; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;');
echo $this->Form->submit('/img/axiaepaysecurebuttongray_med.png', $options);
echo $this->Form->end();
```

Comment: What if you want text as well.